# How to load WMS in C++ with GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, wms, c++

I am trying to load a WMS into my C++ program to use it as a `GDALDataset`. The problem is that I am able to load the WMS but every time I am doing a `GetRasterCount()` I get `0`; and every time I am trying to do a `GetRasterBand(0)` I get `"Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)"`.

I was doing the same thing for WFS (`GetLayerCount()` and `GetLayer(0)`) and it was working fine.

Here is my code:

```
GDALAllRegister();
GDALDataset *poDS = static_cast<GDALDataset*>(
poDS = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpenEx("https://geowebservices.stanford.edu/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&request=GetCapabilities", GDAL_OF_RASTER,NULL,NULL,NULL ));

if( poDS == NULL )
{
    std::cout << "Dataset is empty" << std::endl;
    GDALClose( poDS );
    exit( 1 );
}

std::cout << "THE DATASET CONTAINS THIS MANY RASTER BANDS : " << poDS->GetRasterCount() << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < poDS->GetRasterCount(); i++){

    GDALRasterBand  *band;
    band = poDS->GetRasterBand(i);
    std::cout << band->GetXSize() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: There are no rasters in a WMS Capabilities response, just like there are no features in a WFS Capabilities response.  What happens if you use GetLayerCount() and GetLayer(0) on the WMS Capabilities?

Comment: I still get 0 for GetLayerCount() and GetLayer(0) doesn't give me an error but if I do a GetName() afterwards, I get a segmentation core dumped error.

Comment: maybe the problem comes from the wms ?

Comment: gdalinfo "https://geowebservices.stanford.edu/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&request=GetCapabilities" works fine so I would guess the WMS is fine